# ODE with one random parameter(following Ornstein–Uhlenbeck process )

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I have an ODE system with one random parameter, $\alpha$. $X \in \mathbb{R^2}$ and is governed by 
$$\dot{X}=f(X,\alpha (t))$$
where $\alpha$ is random parameter the follows a Ornstein–Uhlenbeck process. That is
$$d\alpha(t)=-\theta \alpha_t dt+\sigma dW(t)$$. Now OU process has a stationary distribution https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process

I assume that that the ODE part of the system has a stable node. 
My question is , can i analyse the long run behavior of the system by looking at the behavior of the stable node under the stationary distribution.
I know that I can easily write this system as a proper Ito stochastic differential equation and analyse it numerically, but will the other method be valid? Am I missing something here?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you ever get this answered? I would be curious how to even evaluate this.